# How can get device token for iphone push notifcation under Ad Hoc

Tags: iphone, push, apple-push-notifications

The push notification is working when I use development profile , But it is not working with distribution profile. I am using the code to get the device token as follows:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
    {
        NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
    }
```

I am getting the same device token in production mode as in development mode. I am testing the app as Ad Hoc.

How can I get device token in Ad Hoc or production mode. Because we can NSLog device token on console for debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the `deviceToken` to your server.
If you don't have a server, you can write the `deviceToken` to a file in document directory and use tools like iFunBox to see it.

Comment: I have the code under the function didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: It is as follows:

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/iphone/token.php?token=%@",deviceToken];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

But it is not calling the php script. (The php script contains a mail code).

Comment: The method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" executes only once(first time app regsiterd) for an app. ok? Is there any way to get the device token always to my php script?

Comment: The method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" executes     when the app start,not only once. But if user don't allow push, you can't get the deviceToken.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the developer mode of APNS, use production mode of APNS
i think you are using sandbox when creating the .pem files so remove sandbox and then try again to send pust notification.

Answer (score 0):

How can production build can run on real device? Running an app built by production provisioning profile is prohibited.